# Application of differentiation based on electricity consumption

Tags: derivatives, optimization, applications

A utility company has a small power plant that can produce a kilowatt hours of electricity daily at a cost of 10 - (/10^5) cents each for 0 < x < 8 x 10^5. Consumers will use 10^5(10 - p/2) kilowatt hours of electricity daily at a price of p cents per kilowatt hour. What price should the utility charge to maximize its profit?

Comment: Please, so your efforts. Otherwise it looks you're asking some body to do your home work.

Comment: Start by coming up with an equation that yields the profit in terms price.  Then, how do you take an equation and find the maximum value?